Как вывести элемент DataFrame в pandas без названии колонки и индекса?
Давайте объясню свою проблему на примере этого простого кода:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [1, 3, 5],
    "col2": [2, 4, 6]
    })
print(df.iloc[[0], [0]])

Вывод:
   col1
0     1

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне надо сделать, чтобы получить просто:
1


Да собственно print(df.iloc[0, 0]). Это конкретный элемент. А как у вас со списочными аргументами это опять DataFrame просто получается, поэтому с индексами и колонками печатается. Потому что в списке может быть много элементов и на выходе матрица, хоть и из одного элемента в вашем случае.

@CrazyElf, здесь Вы немного ошибаетесь (или я Вас неправильно понял), но я прогнал тот же код, заменив последнюю строку на print(type(df.iloc[[0], [0]])) и получил результат <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, а не int или str.

Смотрите внимательно, у вас iloc[[0], [0]], у меня iloc[0, 0]. У вас получается на выходе DataFrame, о чём я и писал. У меня на выходе numpy.int64, и это правильно - внутри DataFrame лежат массивы Numpy.

@CrazyElf, извиняюсь, опять невнимательность подводит

Главное, чтобы вы разобрались ))

Я бы рекомендовал использовать не iloc, а iat - он значительно быстрее print(df.iat[0, 0])

@АлексейР Ничо се. Век живи - век учись )  Хотя в общем экономия на спичках, %timeit даёт разницу 25%, если не делать это миллиарды раз, разницу никто не заметит. Вот если бы разница была в разы или на порядки...
